# Implementing SOAP with OSGi in Eclipse

Tags: soap, osgi

I have been developing an application using OSGi-Equinox iwith Eclipse. Now I would liek to implement some web-services. I manage to implement some simple webservices using org.eclipse.equinox.http. Using this package I send HttpServletRequest and return HttpServletResponse, where i write the "answer" in a PrintWriter.

Now I would like that the messages exchanged are SOAP messages and also use WSDL. Can any one point me to a tutorial to do this using eclipse and OSGi? Is jetty a good option?Is there any tutorial with Jetty and OSGi to implement SOAP?

Thanks!

Ana

Answer (score 3):

I found a very interesitng tutorial using apache:

http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html